# Interpolating output from given raster file using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a continuous raster file [File No. 1] which contains the coordinates of locations (latitude and longitude) and a output (say, X) associated with it.

I have another table in CSV format (File No. 2) which contains coordinates (latitude and longitude) of selected set of locations but the values of these coordinated do no exactly match with those in File No.1.

Is there a way to determine the approximate output X associated with the coordinates in File No. 2 using some of linear spatial interpolation using ArcMap?

Comment: Depending on your data a quick & dirty solution could be to buffer the raster points & then do a spatial join with the buffer & the CSV file

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about QGIS or ArcMap in this particular question.